# My applicationDidFinishLaunching crashes when I alloc init a NSMetaDataQuery.... Help please

Tags: ios5, icloud

I am updating my app to use iCloud and want my iOS deployment target to remain 3.2.  I am conditionally shielding any iOS 5 calls to prevent any back level versions from crashing.  My applicationDidFinishLaunching looks like...

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 

NSLog(@"Launching Began...");
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


//  Getting the documentsPath.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


//  Setting up the mainCarList

//unarchive the saved carlist 
NSString *archivePathFilename = [documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"/carlist.archive"];    
self.mainCarList = nil;
self.mainCarList = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:archivePathFilename] retain];

//if OS version => 5.0 then 
NSString *reqSysVer = @"5.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching iOS version > 5.0");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(carListDocumentStateChanged) name:@"UIDocumentStateChangedNotification" object:Nil];


    NSString *carListDocumentURLString = [documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"/mainCarListDocument.CLD"];
    self.mainCarListDocumentURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:carListDocumentURLString]; //sets the local save location only in this property


    Class cls = NSClassFromString (@"NSMetadataQuery");
    if (cls) {
        NSMetadataQuery *query;
        query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];  // <------- This crashes when running v4.3 iPhone sim.
     /*
        NSMetadataQuery *query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];

        [self setDocumentMetaDataQuery:query];
        [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDataScope]];
        [query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, @"mainCarListDocument.CLD"]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(queryDidFinishGathering) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:Nil];

        BOOL didStart = NO;
        didStart = [query startQuery];

        if (didStart) {
            NSLog(@"documentMetaDataQuery started");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error starting documentMetaDataQuery");
        }
   */
        [query release];

    }


...
```

I think something is going on at compile time since the "Launching Began" log is not posted.  The conditional block works correctly.  If I comment out the query's alloc init, then the block gets ran only if iOS 5 is running.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use cls instead of NSMetadataQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following code:

```
NSMetadataQuery *query;
query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
```

By this code:

```
id query;
query = [[cls alloc] init];
```